# How to connect plumbing to a trap adapter which is already installed?

Tags: plumbing, drain, pvc

I'm replacing the drain plumbing from my bathroom sink, and there is currently a 1-1/4" male threaded PVC fitting coming from the wall, which I assume is a trap adapter that was installed at some point in the past.  I have the nut from it and understand it should tightly clamp around a new piece of pipe, but I can't seem to make it work.  There was no gasket there - should there be one?  How do I go about attaching the plumbing to this threaded fitting?  Thanks in advance for any advice you can provide!![image]

Comment: Pictures would be very helpful, if you can include a ruler or tape measure for scale that would also be helpful.

Comment: Some PVC connections include a native gasket, while others (like your drain assembly) have a movable one. Without more details I'm not sure we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

The fitting you show inthe picture is probably a "desanco" fitting. A tail piece or J bend is slipped into the fitting and a gasket and jam nut seal the joint. This J bend is usually part of a P trap assembly. If in doubt, go to a big box store, show them a picture and they can show you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

It is supposed to have a gasket. Like the one you get with a trap adapter. 
Install 1 1/4" P trap, then you are good to go.